# Unsubscribe observable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, rxjs, observable

I am using [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) to make a http request in my Node.js application. I want to convert this to an RxJS observable but i don't know how to unsubscribe. What is an efficient methods to do this?

```
public getResponse(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const url = config.url;

    var options = {
        uri: `${url}`,
        body: JSON.stringify(providerResponse),
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const responseObs = from(request(options)); // convert promise to observable using from

    responseObs.subscribe(response => {
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
        res.send(response)
    }, error => {
        console.error(error)
    })
};
```

Comment: You should return `responseObs.subscribe(...)`

Comment: if i return subscription. this will automatically unsubscribe?

Answer (score 1):

`from` converts promises to observables that emit a single value and complete when a promise is settled. The code is already usable, there's no need to unsubscribe completed observable.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for great info. do i need to make error handling during convertion `const responseObs = from(request(clientServerOptions).catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            }));`

Comment: No. If you suppress the error, `subscribe` success callback will be called with `undefined` as a response. As for this example, observables aren't beneficial here at all. They just prevent you from using async/await.